# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Russian Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://russian.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Как правильно: «на GitHub» или «в GitHub»?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%c2%ab%d0%bd%d0%b0-github%c2%bb-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%c2%ab%d0%b2-github%c2%bb)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to find Russian sheet music?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2224/how-to-find-russian-sheet-music)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Translation for "PhD"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/translation-for-phd)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to write a request letter in Russian?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/how-to-write-a-request-letter-in-russian)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Fully expanded form of the dates (years, specially) and their case aspects](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/fully-expanded-form-of-the-dates-years-specially-and-their-case-aspects)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [When "кде" became "где"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/when-%d0%ba%d0%b4%d0%b5-became-%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Not god-alluding expressions equivalent to "боже мой!", "о господи!"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/not-god-alluding-expressions-equivalent-to-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why/How these names have different grammatical endings: Marija - Natalija](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2268/why-how-these-names-have-different-grammatical-endings-marija-natalija)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why "лук" is a mass noun while "огурец" is not?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/why-%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%ba-is-a-mass-noun-while-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%86-is-not)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Слово "Бог": с прописной или со строчной](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)